# Java tagged union / sum types

Tags: java, haskell, algebraic-data-types

Is there any way to define a sum type in Java? Java seems to naturally support product types directly, and I thought enums might allow it to support sum types, and inheritance looks like maybe it could do it, but there is at least one case I can't resolve.
To elaborate, a sum type is a type which can have exactly one of a set of different types, like a tagged union in C.
In my case, I'm trying to implement haskell's Either type in Java:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

but at the base level I'm having to implement it as a product type, and just ignore one of its fields:

```
public class Either<L,R>
{
    private L left = null;
    private R right = null;

    public static <L,R> Either<L,R> right(R right)
    {
        return new Either<>(null, right);
    }

    public static <L,R> Either<L,R> left(L left)
    {
        return new Either<>(left, null);
    }

    private Either(L left, R right) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("An Either cannot be created with two values");
        }
        if (left == right)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("An Either cannot be created without a value");
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I tried implementing this with inheritance, but I have to use a wildcard type parameter, or equivalent, which Java generics won't allow:

```
public class Left<L> extends Either<L,?>
```

I haven't used Java's Enums much, but while they seem the next best candidate, I'm not hopeful.
At this point, I think this might only be possible by type-casting `Object` values, which I would hope to avoid entirely, unless there's a way to do it once, safely, and be able to use that for all sum types.

Comment: Scala uses inheritance to emulate sum types. You can't force Java to make a type "sealed" (that is, someone else could come along and write something foolish like `class Apollo11 extends Either<Integer, Integer>`), but you can simply not write any more subclasses yourself and hope for the best. "Safely" doing this is outside of the abilities of Java's type system, but doing it is possible with inheritance.

Comment: Looking at the signature of [`Collections.newSetFromMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)) I think it should be perfectly ok to just define an arbitrary generic type, such as `class Left<L> extends Either<L, Object>`.

Comment: @silvio a `final` class cannot be extended in Java.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Yes, but we want to extend it a limited number of times and then lock it. Scala has this in the form of the `sealed` keyword, but in Java, you either leave a class open to everyone or make it `final` and block even yourself from inheriting.

Comment: By making all constructors `package-private`, inheritance can be limited to the enclosing package though. Instantiation must then be performed through static factory, as it is already done here.

Comment: @Izruo Hmm, your solution seems right, but I've had trouble putting Functional Interface types into `Object`. Eg `Object a = () -> {};` doesn't compile. Is `Object` still the base of every concrete type?

Comment: You could have a base that is package visible only but have the derived classes final and public.

Comment: As the point of that 'wildcard' is, that the `right` member of an instance of type `Left` is never assigned, this won't matter. By the way, the compiler error is probably because it cannot determine the type of functional interface. It should therefore work with an explicit cast: `Object a = (Runnable) () -> {}`, although I don't see a point in this.

Comment: check out https://github.com/pakoito/JavaSealedUnions

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Make `Either` an abstract class with no fields and only one constructor (private, no-args, empty) and nest your "data constructors" (`left` and `right` static factory methods) inside the class so that they can see the private constructor but nothing else can, effectively sealing the type.

Use an abstract method [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either) to simulate exhaustive pattern matching, overriding appropriately in the concrete types returned by the static factory methods. Implement convenience methods (like [`fromLeft`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:fromLeft), [`fromRight`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:fromRight), [`bimap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap), [`first`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:first), [`second`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:second)) in terms of `either`.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

public abstract class Either<A, B> {
    private Either() {}

    public abstract <C> C either(Function<? super A, ? extends C> left,
                                 Function<? super B, ? extends C> right);

    public static <A, B> Either<A, B> left(A value) {
        return new Either<A, B>() {
            @Override
            public <C> C either(Function<? super A, ? extends C> left,
                                Function<? super B, ? extends C> right) {
                return left.apply(value);
            }
        };
    }

    public static <A, B> Either<A, B> right(B value) {
        return new Either<A, B>() {
            @Override
            public <C> C either(Function<? super A, ? extends C> left,
                                Function<? super B, ? extends C> right) {
                return right.apply(value);
            }
        };
    }

    public Optional<A> fromLeft() {
        return this.either(Optional::of, value -> Optional.empty());
    }
}
```

Pleasant and safe! No way to screw it up. Because the type is effectively sealed, you can rest assured that there will only ever be two cases, and every operation ultimately must be defined in terms of the `either` method, which forces the caller to handle both of those cases.

Regarding the problem you had trying to do `class Left<L> extends Either<L,?>`, consider the signature `<A, B> Either<A, B> left(A value)`. The type parameter `B` doesn't appear in the parameter list. So, given a value of some type `A`, you can get an `Either<A, B>` for *any* type `B`.

Comment: I would introduce an enum into this, to give a way to exhaustively match against the cases

Comment: It might be wise to name the method generics differently from the class' generics. E.g., maybe `AL`, `BL`, `AR`, and `BR` so that it's easy to distinguish which ones are being used where.

Comment: note this approach can be industrialised with a JSR269 annotation processor to generate the boilerplate (the static left and right methods and others, like hashCode/equals). See my project [Derive4J](https://github.com/derive4j/derive4j#derive4j-java-8-annotation-processor-for-deriving-algebraic-data-types-constructors-pattern-matching-and-more).

Comment: @vtosh that was because I was using anonymous-class type-argument inference, which was added in Java 9, but I've edited it to make the type arguments explicit so that now it will compile on Java 8

Answer (score 33):

A standard way of encoding sum types is Boehm–Berarducci encoding (often referred to by the name of its cousin, Church encoding) which represents an algebraic data type as its *eliminator*, i.e., a function that does pattern-matching. In Haskell:

```hs
left :: a -> (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r
left x l _ = l x

right :: b -> (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r
right x _ r = r x

match :: (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> ((a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r) -> r
match l r k = k l r

-- Or, with a type synonym for convenience:

type Either a b r = (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r

left :: a -> Either a b r
right :: b -> Either a b r
match :: (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> Either a b r -> r
```

In Java this would look like a visitor:

```java
public interface Either<A, B> {
    <R> R match(Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right);
}

public final class Left<A, B> implements Either<A, B> {

    private final A value;

    public Left(A value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> R match(Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right) {
        return left.apply(value);
    }

}

public final class Right<A, B> implements Either<A, B> {

    private final B value;

    public Right(B value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> R match(Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right) {
        return right.apply(value);
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
Either<Integer, String> result = new Left<Integer, String>(42);
String message = result.match(
  errorCode -> "Error: " + errorCode.toString(),
  successMessage -> successMessage);
```

For convenience, you can make a factory for creating `Left` and `Right` values without having to mention the type parameters each time; you can also add a version of `match` that accepts `Consumer<A> left, Consumer<B> right` instead of `Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right` if you want the option of pattern-matching without producing a result.

Comment: This already mirrors the remainder of my implementation what I'd hidden in the `...`, as it's adjacent to the actual issue of implementing the sum type, but it is definitely an important part of the Either type's implementation

Comment: A main selling point of this approach is that there is no need to use type casts (nor `instanceof`) to eliminate the sum type. In other words, this would also work in a fragment of Java where potentially dangerous constructs such as type casts are forbidden.

Comment: FWIW, I have explored a similar ADT encoding in Java in my blog: https://garciat.com/2020/05/07/java-adt/

Answer (score 10):

Alright, so the inheritance solution is definitely the most promising. The thing we would like to do is `class Left<L> extends Either<L, ?>`, which we unfortunately cannot do because of Java's generic rules. However, if we make the concessions that the type of `Left` or `Right` must encode the "alternate" possibility, we can do this.

```
public class Left<L, R> extends Either<L, R>`
```

Now, we would like to be able to convert `Left<Integer, A>` to `Left<Integer, B>`, since it doesn't actually *use* that second type parameter. We can define a method to do this conversion internally, thus encoding that freedom into the type system.

```
public <R1> Left<L, R1> phantom() {
  return new Left<L, R1>(contents);
}
```

Complete example:

```
public class EitherTest {

  public abstract static class Either<L, R> {}

  public static class Left<L, R> extends Either<L, R> {

    private L contents;

    public Left(L x) {
      contents = x;
    }

    public <R1> Left<L, R1> phantom() {
      return new Left<L, R1>(contents);
    }

  }

  public static class Right<L, R> extends Either<L, R> {

    private R contents;

    public Right(R x) {
      contents = x;
    }

    public <L1> Right<L1, R> phantom() {
      return new Right<L1, R>(contents);
    }

  }

}
```

Of course, you'll want to add some functions for actually accessing the contents, and for checking whether a value is `Left` or `Right` so you don't have to sprinkle `instanceof` and explicit casts everywhere, but this should be enough to get started, at the very least.

Comment: What is the role of the enclosing `EitherTest` type?

Comment: Nothing in particular. Just wrapping it all in one file so all the classes can be public. Java requires that each file have at most one public class. If you implement this solution in your project, there's no reason to have `EitherTest`.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance *can* be used to emulate sum types (Disjoint unions), but there are a few issues you need to deal with:

1. You need to take care to keep others from adding new cases to your type. This is especially important if you want to exhaustively handle every case you might encounter. It's possible with a non-final super class, and package-private constructor.
2. The lack of pattern patching makes it quite difficult to consume a value of this type. If you want compiler-checked way to guarantee that you've exhaustively handled all cases, you need to implement a match function yourself.
3. You're forced into one of two styles of API, neither of which are ideal:

   - All cases implement a common API, throwing errors on API they don't support themselves. Consider [`Optional.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--). Ideally, this method would only be available on a disjoint type who's value is known to be `some` rather than `none`. But there's no way to do that, so it's an instance member of a general `Optional` type. It throws `NoSuchElementException` if you call it on an optional whose "case" is "none".
   - Each case has a unique API that tells you exactly what it's capable of, but that requires a manual type check and cast every time you wish to call one of these subclass-specific methods.
4. Changing "cases" requires new object allocation (and adds pressure on the GC if done often).

TL;DR: Functional programming in Java is not a pleasant experience.

Comment: You missed a third case, where the common API provides only the `switch`, which unwraps the structure for you and provides control flow, like Haskell's pattern match. I doubt there would be a situation where you need to decide control flow based on the type, but then use the whole object, instead of just the contained value.

Comment: See [Jon Purdy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48143514/6112457) for something similar to my implementation

Comment: @ZoeyHewll Yeah. One of the issues though, is that different cases can have can different numbers of values, with different types. Java doesn't give you a way to deal with that

Comment: [It definitely does](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0eea8d3768c571a9230f54fd31d43ba0)

Comment: By passing in the functions to be called in each case, you can have the enclosed values passed to a function that expects exactly that number of values, of the required types

Comment: @ZoeyHewll I'm not quite getting it, could you show me an example of the usage?

Comment: See my comment on the gist for a better formatted example, but:
`Maybe<Integer> m = someOperation();
m.match(
      (Integer value) -> System.out.println("value = " + value),
      () -> System.out.println("there is no value")
);`

Comment: @ZoeyHewll I see, so the super class declares an abstract match method that takes `n` functions for each of the `n` cases, each taking as parameters the values associated with that case. Then each subclass calls one of of those `n` functions, passing it members (associated values) as arguments. Correct?

Comment: Yes. The `match` function directly mirrors Haskell's `case` expression in this regard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162777/discussion-between-alexander-and-zoey-hewll).

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

With Java 21, you can do

```java
public sealed interface Either<A, B> permits Left, Right {}
public record Left<A, B>(A value) implements Either<A, B> {}
public record Right<A, B>(B value) implements Either<A, B> {}
```

```java
public <A,B,R> R match(Either<A,B> a, Function<A,R> left, Function<B,R> right){
    return switch(a){
        case Left<A,B>(A value) -> left.apply(value);
        case Right<A,B>(B value) -> right.apply(value);
    };
}
```

### Long version

In recent Java versions, there have been a lot of additions to the Java language due to [project Amber](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/) which are useful for that kind of problem.
Namely, Java added [Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), [sealed classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409), [record patterns](https://openjdk.org/jeps/440), [switch patternmatching](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441) and [switch expressions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361).

Since [Sealed classes have been introduced in Java 17](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409), you can now use these to make an `Either` type. Sealed classes ensure there cannot be any other subclasses.
In your case, the type system guarantees that your `Either` objects are either `Left` or a `Right` objects but not anything else.

I will adapt [Jon Purdy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48143514/10871900) with sealed classes.

```java
public sealed interface Either<A, B> permits Left, Right{
    <R> R match(Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right);
    static <A, B> Left<A, B> left(A value){
        return new Left<>(value);
    }
    static <A, B> Right<A, B> right(B value){
        return new Right<>(value);
    } 
}

public record Left<A, B>(A value) implements Either<A, B> {

    @Override
    public <R> R match(Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right) {
        return left.apply(value());
    }
}

public record Right<A, B>(B value) implements Either<A, B> {

    @Override
    public <R> R match(Function<A, R> left, Function<B, R> right) {
        return right.apply(value());
    }
}
```

I have also added two things for convenience:

- `static` factory methods which can be used for instantiating `Either` objects without the `Left`/`Right` classes
- I have converted `Left`/`Right` classes to [records (available since Java 16)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) which are essentially immutable data classes.

These changes allow accessing the value once you know whether it is a `Left` or `Right` object.
With [switch patternmatching](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441) and [record patterns](https://openjdk.org/jeps/440) which will both be finalized in Java 21, you can conveniently `switch` between the `Left` and `Right` type:

```java
Either<L, R> a= ...;
switch(a){
    case Left<L,R>(L value) -> doLeft(value);
    case Right<L,R>(R value) -> doRight(value);
}
```

You can also use [switch expressions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) for making this `switch` statement an expression:

```java
Either<L, R> a= ...;
ResultType result = switch(a){
    case Left<L,R>(L value) -> computeLeftResult(value);
    case Right<L,R>(R value) -> computeRightResult(value);
}
```

This is essentially equivalent to the `match` method.

If you prefer that to the `match` method, you can simplify the code:

```java
public sealed interface Either<A, B> permits Left, Right {}

public record Left<A, B>(A value) implements Either<A, B> {}

public record Right<A, B>(B value) implements Either<A, B> {}
```

and you can still match using the `switch` construct as mentioned before:

```java
Either<L, R> a= ...;
ResultType result = switch(a){
    case Left<L,R>(L value) -> computeLeftResult(value);
    case Right<L,R>(R value) -> computeRightResult(value);
}
```

### Alternative: common supertype

If the types naturally belong together can add an interface to both types, you can make that sealed as well:

```java
//please use a better name for your specific use-case
public interface AOrB permits A, B {
    //possible common functionality
}

public class A implements AOrB{
    //specific functionality for A
}

public class B implements AOrB{
    //specific functionality for B
}
```

You can then switch over them like:

```java
public <R> R matchAB(AOrB aOrB, Function<A,R> left, Function<B,R> right){
    return switch(aOrB){
        case A a -> left.apply(a);
        case B b -> right.apply(b);
    };
}
```

In many cases, you might also want to use records for `A` and `B`.

Comment: I don't see too much benefit in implementing the Either<L,R>-type when you can just do `abstract sealed class LR permits L,R` and switch-pattern-match on LR with compiletime safety. The goal of this question as I originally read it was to have ADTs in Java. Now, java has ADTs, but the syntax is different from what OP imagined.

Comment: You might not always have control over `L` and `R`;.

Comment: that is true, I imagined the common use case where you have some known classes L and R and want to take the sum type, while your question works with generic L,R as well. Now that I see the value of `Either` even with new java, I believe it is the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a very different solution, that does not make use of inheritance / abstract classes / interfaces. On the downside, it requires some effort for each new "sum type" defined. However, I think it has many advantages : it is safe, it only uses basic concepts, it feels natural to use, and allows for more than 2 "subtypes".

Here is a proof of concept for binary trees because it's more practical than "Either", but you can just use the comments as the guideline to build your own sum type.

```
public class Tree {

// 1) Create an enum listing all "subtypes" (there may be more than 2)
enum Type { Node, Leaf }

// 2) Create a static class for each subtype (with the same name for clarity)
public static class Node {
    
    Tree l,r;
    
    public Node(Tree l, Tree r) {
        
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }
    
}

public static class Leaf {
    
    int label;
    
    public Leaf(int label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    
}

// 3) Each instance must have:
// One variable to indicate which subtype it corresponds to
Type type;

// One variable for each of the subtypes (only one will be different from null)
Leaf leaf;
Node node;

// 4) Create one constructor for each subtype (it could even be private)
public Tree(Node node) {
    
    this.type = Type.Node;
    this.node = node;
    
}

// 5) Create one "factory" method for each subtype (not mandatory but quite convenient)
public static Tree newNode(Tree l, Tree r) {
    return new Tree(new Node(l,r));
}

public Tree(Leaf leaf) {
    
    this.type = Type.Leaf;
    this.leaf = leaf;
    
}

public static  Tree newLeaf(int label) {
    return new Tree(new Leaf(label));
}

// 6) Create a generic "matching" function with one argument for each subtype
// (the constructors ensure that no "null pointer exception" can be raised)
public <T> T match(Function<Node,T> matchNode, Function<Leaf,T> matchLeaf) {
    
    switch (type) {
    case Node:
        return matchNode.apply(node);
    case Leaf:
        return matchLeaf.apply(leaf);
    }
    return null;
    
}

// 7) Have fun !
// Note that matchings are quite natural to write.
public int size() {
    
    return match(
            node -> 1 + node.l.size() + node.r.size(),
            leaf -> 1
    );
    
}

public String toString() {
    
    return match(
            node -> {
                String sl = node.l.toString();
                String sr = node.r.toString();
                return "Node { "+sl+" , "+sr+" }";
            },
            leaf -> "Leaf: "+leaf.label
    );
    
}


public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    Tree node1 = Tree.newNode(Tree.newLeaf(1),Tree.newLeaf(2));
    Tree node2 = Tree.newNode(node1,Tree.newLeaf(3));
    
    System.out.println(node2.size());
    System.out.println(node2);
    
}
}
```

Feel free to express criticism, I'm genuinely interested in this topic and will be happy to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import java.util.Optional;

public interface Either<L, R> {
  default Optional<L> left() { return Optional.empty();}
  default Optional<R> right() { return Optional.empty();}

  static <L, R> Either<L, R> fromLeft(L left) {
    return new Either<L, R>() {
      @Override public Optional<L> left() { return Optional.of(left); }
    };
  }

  static <L, R> Either<L, R> fromRight(R right) {
    return new Either<L, R>() {
      @Override public Optional<R> right() { return Optional.of(right); }
    };
  }
}
```

The difference to other solutions proposed here is not deep, but stylistic.