# Java function signature accept single enum value

Tags: java

I have a Java class with multiple "type" values, and a class which can take one of those types.

I'm trying to change the implementation of the constructor depending the `Type` enum using Java's type system, but can't find any information on how to do it.

```java
public enum Type {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class Action {
    public Action(Type.A type, String value) {}
    public Action(Type.B type, Float value) {}
    public Action(Type.C type, String value) {}
}
```

Is something to this effect possible in Java? Like it is in Typescript for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that what you are trying to model is three related types

- A, with a string value,
- B, with a float value, and
- C, with a string value.

If so, Java pretty much wants you to make three subclasses, A, B, and C, of an abstract base class, because, well, Java doesn't really do disjoint sum types (a.k.a. disjoint union types, tagged union types) very well.

Information on how to have a single type with "tags" (that's where the name tagged union or tagged sum comes from) is discussed in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48143268/831878). It might be best to check out that question at some point, since many ideas are offered; most use generics.

IMHO, Java never really got a proper way to do sum types. Java 8 introduced optionals, but "only optionals," so proper sum types take some work.

So in the meantime, consider the usual Java workarounds:

- subclasses (sigh)
- static factory methods (since you cannot overload constructors with your enum: A, B, and C all belong to the same type).

EDIT: See the great answer by @9000 which shows exactly how to implement the static factory methods.

Answer (score 13):

No, what you wrote will not compile.

You can have named factory methods + a private constructor to achieve a similar result:

```java
public class Action {
  private Action(Type discriminator, String s, Float f) {...}
  public static ofA(String value) { return new Action(Type.A, value, null); }
  public static ofB(Float value)  { return new Action(Type.B, null, value); }
  public static ofC(String value) { return new Action(Type.C, value, null); }
}
```

The constructor will likely have a number of if / else branches. (Sorry, algebraic types and pattern matching are not yet available in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like A and C are from the same "type" family and B belongs to another Type.
In such a case you should define two types.
If you want to be able to have both types be treated as the same "family", have them implement the same interface:

```
interface Type {
}

enum Type1 implements Type {
    A,
    C
}

enum Type2 implements Type {
    B
}



public class Action {
    public Action(Type1 type, String value) {}
    public Action(Type2 type, Float value) {}        
}
```