# Distinguish between a string and a URL in Java data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

So, my one of my Java datamodel is as follows:

```
public class Template extends ITemplate {
    private String templateId;
    private Map<String,String> dynamicFields;
}
```

Now the `dynamicFields` will contain some fields which are going to be URLs. Is there a way to edit the data model, so that it is easily inferrable which of the map elements correspond to string and which represent URLs?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a tagged union type?

Comment: How would a tagged union work in this case?

Comment: You would make an `Either<String, URL>` type, and use that as the map's value. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48143268/5133585).

Comment: @Sweeper at which point he would only be able to add URL's, if I'm not mistaken, that is not the goal, he just wants to check which is a common String, and which is a URL. He should create a new Object containing two fields: a String and a URL, and based on which is entered, he knows the type

Comment: @Stultuske Did you misread that as `Map<String, URL>`? "a new Object containing two fields: a String and a URL" *is* how`Either<String, URL>` could be implemented.

Comment: indeed,my mistakeµ

Comment: URLs are Strings. You must define how to distinguish Strings that are URLs from Strings that are not URLs.

Comment: I think you need to describe your higher level goal. What you are asking is possible, but what will be a good solution depends on requirements and details that you have not yet told us. So the bigger picture, please?

Comment: How do you intend to use `dynamicFields`? (Assuming you will be able to solve your current problem of distinguishing between a URL and a string (which isn't a URL).)